# form embed on email (with default values)

Tags: html, forms, email

I am trying to embed a form on a email with all the fields (inputs and textarea) filled. The mail seems good, but I find two problems:
1) The form submits clicking every input... Is it be embedded?
2) The main problem is that when I send the email the form tag (on hotmail) and the attribute "name" of the inputs and textarea, disappear (hotmail and ¿thunderbird?).

I am using Contact Form-7 (the wordpress plugin), and I configure it like this:

```
<form action="http://panel.1clicklawyers.net/userQuestions" method="POST">
De: <input value="[your-name]" name="user_name" style="border:0px; width:auto;"><input value="[your-email]" name="user_mail" style="border:0px; width:auto;">
Asunto: <input value="[your-subject]" name="subject" style="border:0px; width:auto;">

<h2>Cuerpo del mensaje:</h2>
<textarea value="[your-message]" name="question" style="border:0px">[your-message]</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Enviar" style="background:#D8531D; color:#333; pading:15px;"> 
</form>
--
Este e-mail se ha enviado vía formulario de contacto desde 1clicklawyers http://www.1clicklawyers.net
```

On the side of the receiver everything seems good, but the names of the inputs and textarea disappear, and on the server side if I make:

```
var_dump($this->input->post()); //Using codeigniter.
var_dump($_POST); //I am not sure if this could work.
```

The result is bool(false).

**MORE TESTINGS**
I was making more tests, using different accounts and clients. The result is the next:

> **Hotmail**: The form tag disappear (and too the attribute name of inputs and text area).
>   **Hotmail on the android outlook client**: When I click on the submit input, it opens a tab of the browser, but it sends me to the url base (panel.1clicklawyers.net) without the last segment (userQuestions).
>   **ThunderBird**: Using a 1clicklawyers.net account. Clicking on the submit it opens a new tab on the browser, but the var_dump shows "*bool(false)*". Could it be because thunderbird removes the attribute name??
>   **Web Mailer**: Using the same account of 1clicklawyers.net, but on the web (using the 1&1 webmailer). I have no problem... I click on the submit and everything works fine.
>   **Gmail**:No problem. A confirm window ask you for permissions to send info, accepting I can see how the var_dump is working fine. OK.

Is there any way to make it works on all clients??

**Possible solution**
One thing that maybe can solve this is use a link with the parameters, something like:

```
<a href="http://panel.1clicklawyers.net/userQuestions?email=[your-email]&name=[your-name]&subject=[your-subject]&question=[your-message]">Send</a>
```

But the get method has a limit of chars, and the message could be too much long for it.

Any other solution??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to make a form within an email. Email clients dont support this feature.

Most email clients takes it as phishing so they dont support it.

You can see a list here of who support it. [link](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/forms/)

Comment: Thanks @Rasmus Bidstrup... finally I joined a mail client on the web platform. Maybe one thing I didn´t comment was that the email address of the receiver wasn´t a gmail or hotmail... it is something like email@domain.com, and now this emails, that come from a contact form on the public web, are received there